# "It takes dedicated PARENTS to produce a good drummer" -- Tell me more

Tags: drums, teaching, children

Motivated by https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/why-is-it-so-hard-to-find-a-good-drummer?noredirect=1#comment55597_38814, which had a comment that stated:

> It takes dedicated PARENTS to produce a good drummer.

I'd like to know more about this -- the DOs and DON'Ts for parents of a young person who enjoys drumming.

Comment: I removed the support tag because it's too general and won't really group questions in a way that makes sense or is useful down the line.

Comment: This is too broad and not specifically about music. Just support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hearing (or even listening to !) a rookie drummer practising is not easy. From a parent's point of view there has to be dedication to put up with the noise. Provision of a suitable place to practise, where there is enough room for a kit, and neighbours don't get upset, isn't easy. Have a big detached house, or money to provide a rehearsal room. Have a vehicle large enough to provide transport, pay for lessons, buy a drumkit in the first place. Those are just a few considerations.

Drumming is essentially not a solo career, and it's not tuneful. You can't listen to a song your offspring is practising and recognise it easily. All this doesn't make a GOOD drummer, but it certainly helps along the way. As a parent, encouragement is a good thing to provide, so sitting in and listening is a must. Not many people can do that for long, I guess. Most parents would rather their son/daughter play any other instrument than drums - unless there's a drumkit in the house already - but that's a different scenario.

Looking forward to Tom's and Todd's answers...

Comment: I'm doing well so far on everything you mentioned except the packing up and transporting part.  I haven't been asked to do that yet.  But our drumkit is a hand-me-down, with no boxes or cases.  My son is 12.  I guess at some point, if his interest continues, we'll need boxes and cases?  How damaging to his technique and ear is the hand-me-down kit?

Comment: I don't know much about raising a drummer. Not enough to answer, at least.

Comment: @aparente001 - hand me downs are great. Provided they're half reasonable. New heads on old shells works pretty well. When they need mending, it's a good time to get him involved in it. Nothing really to wreck further! Every instrument I take out of the house to gig, rehearse, etc. MUST go in a proper case. Look at pros. Learnt this from bitter experience.